# How to get 3d point of 2d triangle?

Tags: matrices, geometry, 3d

I am writing a 3d graphics engine for a small project. Heres my problem.

I currently have a 3d triangle. I then map each vertex to 2d with the formulas

$ x = 1000*X/Z$

and

$y=1000*Y/Z$

Where x and y are the 2d co-ordinates, and X,Y,Z are the 3d co-ordinate. Now from each mapped vertex I draw the triangle in 2d. However, I am now going to implement a z-buffering system. And that means for each pixel in the 2d triangle, I will need to know it's 3d's co-ordinate counterpart.

I am a little stuck on how to implement this. I tried researching matrices and tried a little algebra myself with no luck. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

EDIT: I store the 3d co-ordinates of each triangle, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: So what are the things you plan to store? Only $x$ and $y$? Then there is no way to find $Z$

Comment: I store x,y,z for all vertices. For a point on the 2d triangle, which may not be a vertex, I would like to know where it is located on the 3d triangle.

Comment: Looks like you’re doing a perpspective projection “by hand.” Most standard references on 3-D graphics will show you how to modify a projection matrix to preserve depth information for $z$-buffering. The idea is to use the “extra” coordinate in the homogeneous coordinates of the image point to encode depth. It’s pretty straightforward to adapt that to the specific projection that you’re using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the projection you're using, the 2D point with coordinates $(x,y)$ corresponds to the 3D line
$\left\{ \left( tx,\ ty,\ t1000\right) \mid t\in\mathbb R \right\}$.
Said differently, any 3D point on that line will be projected to the 2D coordinates $(x,y)$.

Given a 3D triangle $ABC$, it defines 3D plane. If you know a particular 2D point before projection should belong to that 3D plane, just intersect it with the line that matches the point.

Comment: Thank for the help! I have a slight problem with this, Say I have a triangle with points, $(-100,0,100),(0,0,0),(100,0,100)$ Now my 2d point is $(0,0)$ There are many points that could fit this. How can I get it to return 0, the lowest z.

Comment: @teclnol Technically, $(0,0,0)$ *should* be mapped to $(1000\times\frac 00,1000\times\frac 00)$, except that $\frac 00$ is undefined. So no, your 2d point isn't $(0,0)$. If it was $(0,0)$, then the corresponding line would be exactly the $z$-axis. Back to the topic of 3D points with $z=0$, in this context they generally correspond to points at infinity, with the exception of $(0,0,0)$ which is a singularity.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that, What my point was is if the 3d line was on the 2d plane. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: @teclnol If the 3d line lies on the plane that contains the triangle, that means $(0,0,0)$ belongs to the plane. That also means the 3d triangle is projected onto a 2d line segment, so yes one projected 2d point will match several 3d points of the triangle. Given one point of that 2d segment, it is impossible to decide "objectively" which point of the triangle was projected there, since a lot of them where. But since you can find all points of the triangle that match with some clipping, you could just impose a rule to pick one.

Comment: Or better, since that case is degenerate, detect it and do something specific in your application. In many cases, degeneracies cannot be handled with generic code either way.